# Toshibia Satellite C640 automatically scrolls up or down according to its own mood

Tags: 14.04, hardware, scrolling

While reading a pdf file or a webpage or anything that had to be scrolled in order to read it and sometimes books which ran into 500-600 pages and while reading it. due to some error it generally scrolls up to the first page and sometimes to the last page and it disturbs me a lot.

Usually it didn't happened earlier unless i used this laptop for 9 continuous hours and this problem get cropped up.

i  Even tried a usb mouse.. but still the problem remains.. while reading, writting anything which need scrolling... it sometimes automatically scrolls up..

Answer (score 0):

click/point at the line you're reading , sometimes it scrolls up because the automatic line scroll stays up at the very top. so they keep scrolling up back to the top

because it happens to me many times